# App isn't installed в App shortcuts

Tags: java, android

Начал работать с AppShortcuts, создал всё как требует того офф документация:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:targetApi="25">
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_category_transfer"
    android:shortcutId="shortcut_name"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/common_transactions_add_transaction">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetClass=".LauncherActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.sai.android">
    </intent>
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
</shortcut>
```

Протестировал в эмуляторе, иконка с текстом появляется но при попытке перехода по этой вкладке, выдаёт текст

> App isn't installed

Хотя приложение установлено. Возможно, дело в атрибуте `android:action`, так как я еще до конца не разобрался с ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю на дополнение к вопросу:

> Ну у меня эта главная активити, а переходить я хотел во фрагмент

Так как у вас есть Ваша главная активити, то благодаря ней можно попасть в желаемый фрагмент.

Во-первых, стоит всё таки убедиться в правильности написания атрибутов в `shortcuts.xml`. Будет это выглядеть примерно так:

```
<intent
    android:action="com.vm.sai.activities"
    android:targetClass="com.vm.sai.activities.MainActivity"
    android:targetPackage="com.vm.sai">
</intent>
```

А уже в Вашей активити вам придётся реализовать следующую конструкцию в методе `onCreate()`:

```
if("com.vm.sai.activities".equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MainFragment()).commit();
}
```

Ну и конечно ещё раз убедитесь, что в `AndroidManifest.xml` у Вас к главной активити в `intent'e` прописана `meta-data`:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

Также для более детального ознакомления:

[App Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html);

[ShortcutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html);

[ShortcutInfo Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutInfo.Builder.html).

Comment: Надо уметь разбивать такие проблемы как у автора на две: 1 - как оформить shortcut, чтобы intent запустил нужную мне компоненту, 2 - что послать в intent-е, чтобы компонент что-то сделал либо отобразил в соответствии с этим.

Comment: Не понятно, если автор решил №1, чтобы обсуждать №2.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja полностью согласен, но так как в целом реализация не объёмная, решил ответить сразу на два пункта.

Comment: А если валить все в кучу, получается магия типа "я из ярлыка фрагмент запускаю".

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ, всё получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте, что имя пакета приложения в манифесте совпадает с

`android:targetPackage="com.sai.android"`

и здесь укажите полный путь к классу для верности

`android:targetClass=".LauncherActivity"`

Comment: Ну у меня эта главная активити, а переходить я хотел во фрагмент

Comment: Причем здесь это? Шорткаты умеют только посылать интенты, а интенты предназначены для запуска активит. Что у вас там внути, ваша забота.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Вашим комментарием вы вводите человека в заблуждение, можно подумать что запустить фрагмент никак нельзя.

Comment: @Morozov, поясните что вы подразумеваете под "запустить фрагмент"?

Comment: У автора была проблема с обработкой интента из ярлыка системой. Если он уже дошел до отображения определенного фрагмента в активити, вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ну я могу с помощью App Shortcut'a легко перейти не только в активити, но и в нужный мне объект.

Comment: @Morozov, можно пример как минуя Activity, BroadcastReceiver или Service попасть сразу в Fragment, к примеру.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Добавил ответ, пользуйтесь ;)

Comment: @Morozov, спасибо, но незачет, потому что все-таки без активити никак :) И это ничем в принципе не отличается от простого вызова `startActivity()` с правильным интентом.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja речь и не шла что без активити. Я даже специально процитировал в ответе вопрос автора;) а зачёт/незачёт, это такое, главное чтобы автору помогло разобраться ;)

Comment: @Morozov, автор вас и отблагодарит. А я спрашивал о другом, надеялся на что-то оригинальное :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja спасибо за ответ, моя ошибка что не сразу всё уточнил, но всё же вас ответ уступает.

Comment: @Inkognito, без проблем, просто старайтесь формулировать вопросы конкретнее. Будет легче отвечать.